# How to protect directory listings on Apache server from XSS attacks

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess, xss

I am scanning my website with Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner and it is giving a warning that "Possible sensitive directories found" and pointing to my-domain.com/css and similar folders. I have put an index file in all those folder which redirect a direct access to the folder to a 404 page but still the software is giving me warnings. Any idea or a better solution for this...

Comment: Why do you need that *index.html* anyway? Is directory listing enabled on your server? If so, why don’t you just disable it?

Comment: Directory listing is OFF in Apache and also i have put an index.html file in each folder like for css and images but the issue is that the vulnerability scanning software (Acunetix) throws a warning of Possible sensitive directory.

Comment: But why do you have these index documents anyway?

Comment: Just for the Scanner to Avoid giving the warnings in the Report but it still is...

Comment: But why would the scanner raise a warning when an index document is missing? What is the corresponding warning message?

Comment: Probably false positive from the security scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting this in your .htaccess, instead of using the index files.

```
Options -indexes
```